# Converting byte[] to HttpResponse

Tags: java, parsing, httpresponse

I'm using java sockets to communicate with my server. I'm getting http response from the server in a byte[] format. Now I need to parse the headers and content of the byte[]. The sample response I'm getting from server is :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
alternate-protocol: 443:quic,p=0.01
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate
content-disposition: attachment; filename="f.txt"
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 341
content-type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 15 Nov 2014 18:32:55 GMT
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
server: gws
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

1. Either I need an easiest way to parse this in Java (May be a library)
2. Or a way to convert it into HttpResponse object.

Comment: How do you perform the request? You should add relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Apache HttpComponents is your friend in this case.
Please take a look at http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpParser.html